# Issues when searching for specific special characters in string Python

Tags: python, regex, discord, discord.py, special-characters

I'm working on a discord bot in Python that will look for specific trigger words on a blacklist and censor them. I've got it mostly working, but words already being censored gives it issues.
My solution was to search for "||" (for those unfamiliar, putting text between sets of || puts it behind spoiler tags on discord) and then only run the function if the word is NOT between them. The issue I'm running into is actually finding the position of '||'.
This is my first real attempt at using Python, and its mostly been via googling, so sorry if this is something obvious ^^'

Edit for Clarity: an example ideal input-output would be
In: "Omg I'm so dead"
Out: "Omg I'm so d||ead||"
which currently functions
In: "||Omg I'm so dead||"
Ideal Out: "||Omg I'm so dead||
does not currently function and returns the error

My first attempt was using
`censor_pos = [m.span() for m in re.finditer('||', mge, flags=0)]`
where 'mge' is the message. This returned every postion in the string (aka 'dead' would return (0,0)(1,1)(2,2)(3,3),(4,4)) I realized this was because | was a special character.
Next I tried changing it to
`censor_pos = [m.span() for m in re.finditer(re.escape('||'), mge, flags=0)]`
(adding re.escape) which returned
`TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object, got 'NoneType'`
Interestingly, I did try printing censor_pos to the console to see what was going on, and it does seem to be getting the correct position, the error occurs after.

Because I know it could be an issue elsewhere in the code, here's the full function I'm running it in:

```
def Censor_Trigger(mge, word): #function to censor trigger words given a message and a trigger word
    
    censor_pos = [m.span() for m in re.finditer(re.escape('||'), mge, flags=0)] #finds all instances of "||" to know which parts of message are censored
    trigger_pos = [m.span() for m in re.finditer(word, mge, flags=re.IGNORECASE)] #finds all instances of a trigger word, giving positions as tuples in an array
    censored_msg = mge
    print (censor_pos)
    print (trigger_pos)
    y = 0 #variable to account for position change when censoring multiple instances of the same word
    for x in trigger_pos:
        a = 0
        is_censored = False
        for z in censor_pos:
            if  0<=a and (a+1)<(len(censor_pos)):
                if censor_pos[a][1]<=x[0]<=censor_pos[a+1][0]:
                    is_censored = True
                    return
                else:
                    is_censored = False          

            a=a+1
                
        if is_censored == False:
            censored_msg = censored_msg[:x[1]+(y*4)] + "||" + censored_msg[x[1]+(y*4):]
            censored_msg = censored_msg[:(x[0]+1+(y*4))] + "||" + censored_msg[(x[0]+1+(y*4)):]    
            y=y+1
            print(censored_msg)
        else:
            return
        
        
    return censored_msg
```

And it is called in a for loop

```
trigger_words = ["dead", "trigger", "example", "another"] #list of triggers
for x in trigger_words: #runs the function to censor trigger words for all words in the trigger list
                 Mess = Censor_Trigger(Mess, x)
```

The full error is

```
[2023-09-03 19:26:01] [ERROR   ] discord.client: Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Discord Bot Fun\Test Code.py", line 17, in on_message
    Mess = Censor_Trigger(Mess, x)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Discord Bot Fun\Test Code.py", line 37, in Censor_Trigger
    censor_pos = [m.span() for m in re.finditer(re.escape('||'), mge, flags=0)] #finds all instances of "||" to know which parts of message are censored
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\re\__init__.py", line 223, in finditer
    return _compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object, got 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Wait, it looks like you are trying to replace text to "censor" the needed content. Why not use pythons built in `replace` method for strings?

Comment: Give an example of the inputs ```mge, word```. It looks like your ```mge``` input is 'NoneType' and not a string (or whatever you were expecting)

Comment: @ViaTech I'm not necessarily replacing any text. I edit the post to add some examples of the wanted inputs/outputs. I'm not, for example, changing "dead" to "d***" but instead to "d||ead||". I feel like my solution for adding the "||" is functional for this?

Comment: @SurajShourie I added some examples that may help, as well as how I defined the actual List trigger_words, which would be all the words that are censored (I changed the text from the actual triggers for everyone's health and privacy). mge is based on the message sent in the discord server. The one I was testing with was "||dead||"

Comment: IIRC you can't edit another user's message. The Bot wouldn't be able to edit the message in order to add the censoring to it.

Comment: @PedroCaribé Correct! what it actually does is deletes the message and tags the sender with "@ user said: 'censored message'"

Comment: Ah, great. I've posted an answer with the pattern for the replacement.

Comment: You may want to say `re.finditer(r'\|\|', mge)` instead of `re.finditer('||', mge, flags=0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a lot of printing to console mid program, I realized my issue! during my check to see if the censored word was between censor bars, I had added a `return` in the if statements, thus applying nothing to Mess, thus when it tried to run the function again using Mess, it gave the error. The actual code to find and avoid the censor bars was completely functional *facepalm*
For those here looking for the actual answer, the exact line of code I used to identify the censor bars was

```
censor_pos = [m.span() for m in re.finditer(re.escape('||'), mge, flags=0)]
```

The code posted in the question just needs to have the `return` lines taken out of the if statements in the function. I then added an if statement to compare the final value of Mess (the censored message) to message.content (the original message) and only deleted and resent the message if they differed.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish is possible only with messages from your own bot.
As stated in [Message.edit Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message%20edit#discord.Message.edit) the Bot can **Not** edit another user's message, and it will raise a `Forbidden` exception.

The code for replacing, by following the pattern you want, would be something like this:

```py
@bot.listen()
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    censor_words = ["dead", "trigger", "example", "another"]

    matching_item = next((item for item in censor_words if item in message.content), None)
    if matching_item:
        ret_message = message.content.replace(matching_item, f"{matching_item[0]}||{matching_item[1:]}||")
        await message.edit(content=ret_message)
```

If you're looking to delete the previously sent message, and send it back to the user by censoring and tagging him, you would use something like the one below:

```py
@bot.listen()
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    censor_words = ["dead", "trigger", "example", "another"]

    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    
    matching_item = next((item for item in censor_words if item in message.content), None)
    if matching_item:
        user = message.author
        ret_message = message.content.replace(matching_item, f"{matching_item[0]}||{matching_item[1:]}||")
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(content=f"{user.mention}\n{ret_message}")
```

Notice that I've also added a check if the author of the message is the Bot itself, but I don't believe it's needed, since the response will have `||` after the first letter of the word, so it wouldn't trigger the condition.

Comment: The issue isn't with the replacing, I've got that already. my issue is specifically ignoring when the word is *already* censored, I don't want to add more censor bars.

Comment: @Asher you mean, after censoring once your bot sends a new message, and it's getting into a loop re-censoring it's own censored response?

Comment: No, I just don't want to censor messages that the user has already censored themselves. I figured it out though!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your task can be done in just a few lines with [The Best Regex Trick™](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html):

```py
import re

def censor(message, /, word):
  return re.sub(
    fr'(\|\|.+?\|\|)|\b{re.escape(word)}\b',
    lambda match: match[1] or f'{word[0]}||{word[1:]}||',
    message
  )
```

Try it [on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/rVOZOT).

For `word = 'dead'`, the regex looks like this:

```
(\|\|.+?\|\|)    # Match and capture any non-empty sequence wrapped in '||'
|                # or
\bdead\b         # match a whole 'dead'.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/a83j8W/1).

In more abstract terms, this matches both already-censored parts and non-censored taboo words outside of those. To differentiate the two, we use a capturing group which presents *iff* the current match is a censored part (and resolves to `None` otherwise).

That said, the following lambda function places group 1 back to the string or do a `word`-to-`w||ord||` replacement otherwise:

```py
lambda match: match[1] or f'{word[0]}||{word[1:]}||'
```

Do note that this might not work correctly if your word looks like `(foo)`, `.bar`, `lorem'` or similar due to the simple nature of `\b`.